# what is the purpose of HttpOnly cookie if can't access from the front Nextjs app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, cookie-httponly

I have generated signed token and assigned it to httponly secure cookie from the back-end nodejs server. This token include the user id to validate the user is logged in.

Currently, store that generated token in localStorage in the front-end nextjs app. this use to validate the user.

Not using the above httponly secure token at all in the front-end. what's the purpose of having this secure cookie if can't access from the front-end?

I know that local storage isn't secure and I want to eliminate this from the front-end. Finding a solution related to this httponly cookie token.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The frontend doesn't use the cookie. The browser and the backend use the cookie.

When you send another request to the backend, the browser includes the cookie as part of the request headers.

If the frontend needs to know some data from the value of the cookie, you need something on the backend to send that to the frontend, not as a cookie. If the purpose of the cookie is to identify the user, the frontend *doesn't* need to know about it.